# Clear and populate tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a very simple and common scenario: I need to update two tables daily. They are generally joined together and only read by the users (no updates happens besides of my maintenance job, which takes a few minutes to run).

I need the version of the data in the two tables to be in sync - they both need to have the same version of the data at any time. Also, I would like to limit possible downtime and locking as much as possible as the data in the table can be actively queried during updates. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If the data needs to be the same, why do you have 2 copies?

Comment: You can create a staging table first with all the changes and after staging table is completely build, you could just drop(or truncate) the main table and rename (or pouplate it) from staging table. Just a thought

Comment: You should look up replication solutions if the tables need to remain in synch.

Comment: @Larnu to clarify, THE VERSION of the data has to be the same, but the tables contain different data (e.g. Employee and Sales). What I am trying to say is, you cannot have TABLE A with new data and TABLE B with old data.

Comment: Using replication or maintaining one set of data are the two options you have. Anything you are doing manually to synch them is going to have challenges because this is far more complicated than most people realize.

Comment: If the tables contain different data, how can one table contain "old" data while the other "new"? The data is different.

Comment: @Larnu, you have table A and table B from day 1, you update table A with day 2, now you have old data in table B and new data in table A.

Comment: So it's not so much a synchronising issue, but that one table being updated depends on the other; and if the latter fails, then the prior changes should be rolledback as well?

Comment: yeah, potentially if something fails the changes should be rolled back like if they never happened before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the data into a table of the same name in a different schema and swap them out.  Here you load staging.Table1 and staging.Table2 and then swap them with the versions in dbo.  The target table must be empty:

```sql
begin transaction
  truncate table dbo.Table1;
  truncate table dbo.Table2;
  alter table staging.Table1 switch to dbo.Table1;
  alter table staging.Table2 switch to dbo.Table2;
commit transaction
```

I think the swap should be in its own transaction because it will acquire a schema lock.  You can always reload the staging tables numerous times and just swap when the load is successful.  If the process of loading the tables takes some time, the schema lock will interfere with querying system tables, for instance if you open SSMS and try to list the objects.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information to thoroughly answer this question, however, I'll do my best to provide a first pass. I recommend updating your answer with a lot more information.

Assuming that one table is read-only and the other is not, it's possible that a truncate and insert wrapped in one transaction could be a viable solution.

```
begin tran
truncate table tableA;
insert into TableA select * from TableB;
commit;
```

Another is to take a primary key value from both sources, hash the important columns (the ones where differences matter), and then update the tables if the hashes on a particular key don't match.

```
select primary_key, hashbytes('md5', lower(concat(columna,columnb,columnc))) "hash"
from tableA
except
select primary_key, hashbytes('md5', lower(concat(columna,columnb,columnc))) "hash"
from tableB
```

Another option is to identify the records that need to be changed (in several ways, such as using the hash system above), deleting the corresponding PKs and inserting new records to the target table as opposed to a full truncate.

```
/* using example code above .... */
delete from tableA where exists (select 1 from TableB where pk = pk and hash <> hash);
insert into tableA select * from TableB where not exists (select 1 from tableA where pk = pk);
```

Comment: Now, if both tables can receive updates and then we need a synchronize between the two tables, the approach would be different.